# Drupal Jump Menu Dropdown To External Links

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm attempting to create a jump menu of links to external websites, and I would like to be able to order the links within this menu differently depending on the organic group of the current user attempting to access it. So far I've tried to accomplish this using views with nodequeue, and have come somewhat close, but its beginning to feel like a dead end.. Does any module(or combination of modules exist) which would allow me to accomplish this without having to write my own? Ideally each will be able to reorder the links according to their personal preference and override the default ordering of links. but that is not essential at this point

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a role based solution, but it might be in the right direction.

[Menu Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role)

It doesn't work with building a menu out of Views based on an OG permission? You could create multiple displays and it'd be a pain, but you could use [Menu Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_views) and see if that works.

Hope some of this helps.